# On ASP Button click how can i make the server wait from firing until an jquery ajax call is complete on the same button from client side??

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP button in my webform with a button_click of its own in the code behind.I also have a button click event in the client side that should be executed before the server event is fired.
How can i make the server event wait from executing until the Ajax call is complete???

Please help

Comment: Disable form submission at the start of the ajax request and re-enable when completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hidden button which can trigger the code-behind. Once your Ajax call on the Form button ends, you can trigger the hidden button to execute your code-behind.